# Reverse KVM solution

Tags: remote-access, kvm-switch

I need to setup a computer so that it can be operated from two locations. The locations are about 20 meter from each other and the user wants the experience to be the same from both locations, i.e. no remote desktop or anything like that and preferably a seamless switch.

So basically I need a double set of, monitor, keyboard and mouse, and then of course link it together by some kind of suitable hardware.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a "**2-way KVM Extender**" to accomplish this.  ATEN is a big name in KVM switch equipment, and their web site has a section for KVM Extenders here:

ATEN - KVM Extenders
  http://www.aten.com/KVM-Extender.htm

Pictured below is the ATEN KE0220 model, which is very similar to the CE220 model that I set up for one of my clients a few months ago so they can use their computer from their desk or from a service counter at the other side of the shop -- it uses a normal Cat. 5 Ethernet cable in a proprietary way (so you can't plug it in through an ethernet router), and there's no delay in the speed (you feel like the computer is local because keyboard/mouse response is immediate, and video shows up normally):

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I am familiar with KVM switches from Aten, and this one definately seems to suite my needs. I would go for the CE700A instead though because of USB. How was the switch performed (between remote/local) on your unit, is it auto-switching or is it a special keyboard-combo you must learn... (I really hope you don't need to run to local and press a button everytime you want to switch location)?

Comment: Both run at the same time, or only local computer is active.  There's a switch on the local KVM Extender unit to switch between these two modes.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is a KVM Splitter. It enables you to use control a single PC with multiple keyboards, mice and monitors ( Sharing).